# Access GPS and camera devices on mobile devices from mobile websites

Tags: mobile

I'd like to be able to access GPS and Camera devices from websites built for mobile devices. Most particularly the windows mobile, blackberry or android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS is possible. Camera is not.

Take a look at [Geo location lib](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/) most of the method are device/platform specific but a little googling and you should be able to find the correct methods.

For [Blackberry](http://www.tonybunce.com/2008/05/08/Blackberry-Browser-Amp-GPS.aspx)

Comment: can users take pictures and videos before and then select the file via a browser dialog (if that is supported by mobile browsers) and select those files to be uploaded).

Comment: Yes they would be able too :). Standard html file upload should work provided you aren't doing funky ajax stuff.