# Controlling Mobile Devices Camera On A Mobile Site

Tags: java, mobile

We are developing a mobile web application which user's can reach via their mobile phones' browser. (It's not a mobile phone application, it's a web site for mobile phones) .

We want to get (upload) pictures directly from user's telephone's camera. How we can control user's camera ? I know it's not possible for mobile web site. But for example can we use Java for this? Or can we develop small plugins for mobile phones and trigger it, when user click on **Capture a Photo** link ?

Can you give any advices us please? Thanks !

(except this answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373280/access-gps-and-camera-devices-on-mobile-devices-from-mobile-websites) :

> can users take pictures and videos before and then select the file via
>   a browser dialog (if that is supported by mobile browsers) and select
>   those files to be uploaded)

**Q&A's from comments :**

**1) Well what phone operating systems are you targeting? iOS, for example, has no ability to run Java.**

Actually, we are targetting all OS.

Comment: What about the question you linked to did not answer your question?

Comment: Because that question isn't about Java. I think we can do it with Java, or other programming language. Because of this, i have decided to asking your advices.

Comment: Well what phone operating systems are you targeting? iOS, for example, has no ability to run Java.

Comment: Actually, we are targetting all OS. Maybe we can develop a little plugin (or app) for iOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- iOS has no ability to access the camera from a website. You cannot load Java on iOS at all, either.
- Android had the ability to access the camera from HTML [demoed a while back](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/), but I can't find anyplace noting that it actually made it into a release.
- Blackberry as far as I know also has no such ability to access the camera from a website.

If you wish to use Java, you can develop an actual app for Android or Blackberry. iOS apps are written in Objective C.

However, using [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) you can write an app in HTML5 & Javascript and it will create a native iOS (for 3GS or later) or Android app capable of accessing the camera.